# stat_summary: different behavior between qplot & ggplot2 / understanding the paradigm of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm sure this is going to be an 'oh geez' simple answer, but I always have trouble understanding the underlying paradigm with ggplot2 (0.9.3).  With the following data and helper function:

```
ltd <- data.frame(r = c(rnorm(5, 5, 1.5), rnorm(5, 8, 2)),
    f1 = c(rep("L", 5), rep("H", 5)))

seXy <- function (x) {
    m <- mean(na.omit(x))
    se <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(na.omit(x)))
    u <- m + se
    l <- m - se
    c(y = m, ymin = l, ymax = u)
    }
```

This `qplot` request works fine:

```
tp <- qplot(x = f1, y = r, data = ltd, geom = "point")
tp <- tp + stat_summary(fun.data = "seXy", color = "red", geom = "linerange")
print(tp)
```

But this `ggplot2` request does not draw the linerange, and does not give an error (and using the alternative commented line or not does not do anything different):

```
tp <- ggplot()
tp <- tp + geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = r), data = ltd)
#tp <- tp + stat_summary(fun.data = "seXy", color = "red", geom = "linerange")
tp <- tp + stat_summary(fun.data = "seXy", color = "red", geom = "linerange", 
        aes(ymin = ..ymin.., ymax = ..ymax..))
print(tp)
```

What does the second approach need to make the `linerange` show up?  I clearly misunderstand something.  Of course, this is a MWE and the real context is more complex, but I can't troubleshoot that w/o understanding this simple example.  Looks like `qplot` is doing something for me in the background but I don't know what.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem could be that you define data only in `geom_point()` and so `stat_summary()` do not use them.

If you put `data` and `aes()` in `ggplot()` function, then `stat_summary()` gives `linerange`.

```
ggplot(ltd,aes(x = f1, y = r))+geom_point()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = "seXy", color = "red", geom = "linerange")
```

The same result is achieved if `data` and `aes()` is defined inside `stat_summary()`

```
tp <- ggplot()
tp <- tp + geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = r), data = ltd)
tp <- tp + stat_summary(data=ltd,aes(x = f1, y = r),fun.data = "seXy", color = "red", geom = "linerange")
print(tp)
```

Comment: Oh, geez.  I thought it would be my sillyness.  I was having another problem with aesthetics interfering with each other, so I was trying to purge all extraneous items, and I purged the data right out!  Repeat after me: "All layers must have data, aesthetics and geoms!"  Thank you!